# Accessing an external css stylesheet from an xlst transform

Tags: css, xslt

I'm a programming hobbyist, and I've never gotten along well with DOM, so it's al;most certain I'm not finding an answer because it's too obvious to a competent programmer.

That said, several places on the internet are explicit in saying an xalt stylesheet generating a link of the form (From IBM though I've seen others on the web)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
   version="1.0"
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html"indent="no"/>
<xsl:template match="/products">
   <html>
      <head>
         <title>Cascading Style Sheet</title>
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="table.css" 
              title="Style"/>
      </head>
(...)
```

The problem being of course . . . it's not actually working. 
Inspecting elements in DOM for Firefox or IE shows the CSS link there, but the styletab shows no CSS in the document. Taking the same CSS inline works. Using the external stylesheet in a straight html document works. Producing the exact same code as output from an xslt stylesheet, and the CSS is not imported into the resulting document.

Caveat - so far my .xml files and .xsl files have bee in separate folders, but I have put the .css files in the same folders as each for purposes of checking, and so far that has made no difference.

Dead Code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:variable name="context" select="commands/interactive/@context" /> 
  <xsl:variable name="output" select="commands/interactive/@output" /> 
  <xsl:variable name="css" select="commands/interactive/@css" />
  <!-- To Do: 'context' needs to be entered interactively -->
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
    <head>
    <title><xsl:value-of select="commands/@application"/></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./{$css}" />
    </head>
    <body>
    (...)
```

As an aside, it does properly fill ./{$css} in the output, and fails in the exact same fashion when the file is hard coded. Again, works spiffily when output as inline CSS, or the exact same html. So I'm missing some nuance of DOM I'm sure.

Comment: Do you have a public URL we can visit?

Comment: A space is missing in `xsl:output` directive of the first XSLT sample.

Comment: No public URL immediately available.

Comment: Correcting the output declaration made no difference - output as html still identical, still shows the CSS link, still doesn't actually show the CSS in DOM.

I have tried something obvious that I thought of posting this, and am irritable but it did work - move all the files into the same folder, and poof, it works. So something about creating the 'Virtual' html page doesn't seem to work if the xsl and xml files are in separate folders (even with copies of the css in the same folder as one or both of them), but works fine if they're in the same folder.

Seems weird.

Answer (score 1):

Like all really simple problems, after a few hours publicly looking like an idiot it all comes together. For whoever happens to have the same issue, evidently malformed <xsl:output ... /> will allow everything else to load as reasonable (in IE/Firefox), but the css will fail to load even given a correct path.

Additionally any relative paths need to be relative to the xml file the xsl file is transforming, not the xsl file itself. Both checked before, but not checked at a point when they were *both* right - <G>.

Thanks you - Jonnan